# Select a specific time in DB2 from the currenttime

Tags: sql, db2-400

I am trying to do a select and set the time to 10AM in DB2. Ive tried

```sql
SELECT (trunc(sysdate) + 10/24) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

however this sets the time to 0:00:00, im trying to get it set to 10AM, is there a way to do this in DB2?

Comment: `10/24` is probably treated as integer division, resulting in zero. `Try a float instead: `(trunc(sysdate) + cast(10 as float)/24)

Comment: This is still returning the time as 00:00:00.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please can you try this:

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate) + 10 hours FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=260a590620d255dc265ae50408c8b9a7)

Also, in your question example you have one open bracket too many.
it should be: `SELECT (trunc(sysdate) + 10/24) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1`

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, sorry the extra bracket is there because this SQL is part of a larger query. However, this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, happy it was of help to you. No problem, just wanted to point that out so you can maybe correct it in your question...Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
SELECT DateAdd(Hour, 10, sysdate) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```